# Any way to pass always a default props value in to a styled component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am using React + Material UI  + Styled Component. I am trying to create a custom Input field. I want to pass always `size='small'` as props to my component.

In other words, if the user forgets to pass **size**, it always takes **small**. Or if the user by mistake passes any other value other than **small**, it still always takes **'small' only**.

Here is my code:
https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-meadow-utv9bc?file=/src/App.tsx

```
import * as React from "react";
import TextField, { TextFieldProps } from "@mui/material/TextField";
import { styled } from "@mui/material/styles";

const Input = styled(TextField)<TextFieldProps>(
  ({ disabled, multiline, theme }) => {
    return {
      border: `1px solid red`
    };
  }
);

export default Input;
```

I am using like this

```
 <Input label="Outlined" />
```

I want to pass size always **small** Any idea?

Comment: so you want to override it in all cases, you basically want to disallow the user to set it to any value and just always be "small", right ?

Comment: yes correct . this is expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose a simple solution would be to create a component that overrides the `size` prop to always be `"small"` and then style that.

```js
import TextField, { TextFieldProps } from "@mui/material/TextField";
import { styled } from "@mui/material/styles";

const SmallTextField = (props: TextFieldProps) => (
  <TextField {...props} size="small" />
);

const Input = styled(SmallTextField)<TextFieldProps>(
  ({ disabled, multiline, theme }) => {
    return {
      border: `1px solid red`
    };
  }
);

export default Input;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Mui Theme Provider

```
import * as React from "react";
import { createTheme, ThemeProvider } from "@mui/material/styles";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";

const theme = createTheme({
  components: {
    // Name of the component ⚛️
    MuiTextField: {
      defaultProps: {
        size: "small"
      }
    }
  }
});

export default function DefaultProps() {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <TextField />
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

Comment: I do not think the want all the `TextField` components to be `small`. Just their own `Input` component.

Comment: any better solution ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a wrapper that would set `size="small"` and remove `size` from the props with `Omit`, so anyone who uses your `Input` knows he cannot set it with the help of TypeScript errors:

```js
import TextField, { TextFieldProps } from "@mui/material/TextField";
import { styled } from "@mui/material/styles";

const InnerInput = styled(TextField)<TextFieldProps>((props) => {
  return {
    ...props
  };
});
const Input = (props: Omit<TextFieldProps, "size">) => (
  <InnerInput {...props} size="small" />
);
export default Input;
```

[image]